# KeyError: "Field 'commercial_partner_id'

Tags: odoo

I want to install the Purchase Management model, but I get the following error:

**OpenERP Server Error**

```
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20130321-002353\Server\server.\openerp\osv\fields.py",    line 1131, in get

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20130321-002353\Server\server.\openerp\osv\fields.py", line 1197, in _fnct_read

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20130321-002353\Server\server.\openerp\osv\orm.py", line 383, in __getitem__


KeyError: "Field 'commercial_partner_id' does not exist in object 'browse_record(res.partner, 26)'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your addons list and also database

Key error means that field is not available in your database but have some reference

Answer (score 0):

I Updated but it still error 
I fix by 
Create new module like this

```
class res_partner_fix(osv.Model):
    _inherit = "res.partner"
    _columns = {
        'commercial_partner_id': fields.integer("commercial_partner_id"),
    }
```

It work now